# Uncaught TypeError cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm new to Javascript/jquery and having an issue with an app I'm developing.  I am getting an Uncaught TypeError when trying to read a property of an object.  My ultimate goal is for the user to enter something in a text box and based on that input, make an object with the input as a name property. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var playerArray = [];
    var playerIndex = 0;

    function player (name) {
        this.name = name;
        score = 0;
    };

    var addPlayer = function(name){
        playerArray[playerIndex] = new player(name);
        playerIndex++;
    };

    $('#add_players').on('click', '#btn-add', function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=playerNameInput]').val();
        addPlayer(toAdd);
        $('#playerList').append('<div class="ui-block-a" style="padding:1em">' + playerArray[playerIndex].name + '</div>');
    });
});
```

I have searched the site for other issues like this but they are all dealing with APIs or irrelevant issues to mine.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addPlayer()` is incrementing your `playerIndex` counter *after* you've added the object to `playerArray`, which you then use inside your `click` handler. It's not clear based on your code what you're trying to retrieve when you call `playerArray[playerIndex]` (the last element added?) but I would just get rid of the counter and use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var playerArray = [];

    function player (name) {
        this.name = name;
        score = 0;
    }

    var addPlayer = function(name){
        playerArray.push(new player(name));
    };

    $('#add_players').on('click', '#btn-add', function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=playerNameInput]').val();
        addPlayer(toAdd);

        // playerArray[playerArray.length - 1] will always retrieve the last element in the array
        // use playerArray[0] if you always want the first
        $('#playerList').append('<div class="ui-block-a" style="padding:1em">' + playerArray[playerArray.length - 1].name + '</div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: And you just removed the player from the array. pop() is not the right thing to use when you are reading the value. Push is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code

```
var addPlayer = function(name){
     playerArray[playerIndex] = new player(name);  //you store it at an index
     playerIndex++;  //you increment
 };
```

Because index is incremented and there is nothing like the position you are reading.

```
console.log(playerArray[playerIndex]);  //undefined
console.log(playerArray[playerIndex-1]);  //the last entry you added
```

---

Personally I would not rely on the last index. I would return the new player when you create it. Than there is no need to deal with index issues.

```
var playerArray = [];
var playerIndex = 0;

function Player (name) {
    this.name = name;
    score = 0;  //this will be a problem....
};
var addPlayer = function(name){
    var user = new Player(name);
    playerArray.push(user);
    return user;
};

$('#add_players').on('click', '#btn-add', function(){
    var toAdd = $('input[name=playerNameInput]').val();
    var person = addPlayer(toAdd);
    $('#playerList').append('<div class="ui-block-a" style="padding:1em">' + person.name + '</div>');
});
```

Also `score` is going to be a problem.

Comment: Can you help me understand why someone would downvote our answers? You've been doing this longer than I have. We both posted the (correct) answer at the same time. The downvotes confuse me. In any case, I upvoted yours to compensate for your erroneous downvote.

Comment: OP would probably benefit from an explanation as to why "`score` is going to be a problem", given his/her level of experience with JS.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  It was helpful.  I would like to know why you think `score` is going to be a problem

Comment: because it is a random global variable not attached to anything.

Comment: I thought it fell under the scope of the player object.

Comment: There is no `this` and there is no `var` so it is a global.

Answer (score 1):

Your first run is adding 1 to the `playerIndex` that you initialize at 0.

By the time you get to `playerArray[playerIndex].name` for the first time, `playerIndex` is 1 and you are looking for the first value (index 0). You will always be one index behind.